# SQL Query for loans

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

**Question:**

Suppose the following dbo.LoanStatements table was given to you. All the records of the table are shown below. Each record shows when the statement was sent.

```
LoanID StatementDate    OriginalLoanToValue
-------------------------------------------
1       03/15/2005      0.80
1       04/15/2005      0.90
1       05/15/2005      0.90
1       06/15/2005      0.90
2       08/15/2017      66.7
2       09/15/2017      66.7
2       10/15/2017      0.50
3       10/15/2017      0.66
4       10/15/2017      0.55
```

1. Write a SELECT statement (or multiple statements) that returns the
   following result set

   ### LoanID  OriginalLoanToValue

   1       0.90
   2       0.50
   3       0.66
   4       0.55

Attempted solution -

```
SELECT LoanID, OriginalLoanToValue
FROM LoanStatements
WHERE StatementDate IN (
SELECT MAX(StatementDate)
FROM LoanStatements
GROUP BY LoanID
);
```

2. How many statements were sent in 2005? In 2017? Please show the SELECT statement (or multiple statements).

Attempted solution:

**2005:**

```
SELECT LoanID,StatementDate,OriginalLoanToValue
FROM LoanStatements
WHERE year(StatementDate) = 2005;
```

**2017:**

```
SELECT LoanID,StatementDate,OriginalLoanToValue
FROM LoanStatements
WHERE year(StatementDate) = 2017;
```

I do not have any way of checking whether this code is correct this is just what I could come up with little SQL I knew, I would appreciate it if someone could clarify if this is correct or not. Thanks!

Comment: what is your desired output in number 2?

Comment: @JohnWoo I dont have the answer

Comment: Hi... I would recommend to try your statements @ SQL Fiddle. It's an online platform where you can create virtual schema, tables; populate and query them. you do not need to install anything. You'll be easily able to verify your logic then. Link - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: 'No way of checking'?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will go correct if your data type is "DATE","DATETIME","TIMESTAMP","YEAR" for "StatementDate" column.

Comment: If you take any datatype  that i have mentioned above then it will give you result absolutely fine

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean

Comment: What is your datatype for StatementDate column?

Comment: no idea the interviewer just sent the data by an email

Comment: just as I written in the post

Comment: If your datatype of column is anyone of belows, then your queries will work fine. 1. DATE 2.DATETIME 3.TIMESTAMP 4.YEAR

Comment: How would I know just based on the information in the post that was sent by email?

Comment: You must need  know what is your database schema.